# Is there a GUI for opensync?

Tags: 10.10, sync

Every search for a graphical interface for [opensync](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libopensync1exp7) [image: Install libopensync1exp7] gives me outdated information. Is this project still actively developed and is there any working GUI in Ubuntu 10.10?

(No, `multisync-gui` is not in the archives any more!)

Answer (score 3):

There is no opensync gui yet, as soon as opensync stabilises enough someone will make a graphical front end that will rock.

Comment: That's bad news! Well, good news in a way also ... Do I get you right, that we can exclusivly use configuration files at the moment?

Comment: On the Homepage it says:

Comment: To get started with OpenSync? you probably need:

    * OpenSync? itself: it is a library and does not contain any plugins or user interfaces
    * the plugins: there is one plugin per type of thing to synchronize (files, PDAs, smartphones, Google Calendar, whatever)
    * some kind of user interface (UI): such as Multisync or Kitchensync. Multisync contains both a command line tool (msynctool) and a GUI written in GTK.

Comment: Btw offtopic: How to add linebreaks to comments?

Comment: @piedro: So the website is a bit out of date and there are two versions of opensync, the old 0.19 versions and the 0.4x versions which are considered in development. There are gui tools for 0.19 but they aren't very good.

Comment: thx for your comment! Still it's disappointing: Syncing is a core feature of modern PIM and there's not even a website with correct information. Evolution should have working syncing modules but it doesn't. And it hasn't changed since about 5 years ... I'm disappointed.

Comment: The evolution data service isn't a modern PIM. the FreeDesktop is missing a complete PIM, Akonadi is working it's way there, just like tracker. But we have too many fancy programmers doing fancy things and not enough basics.

Comment: Completely agree! Same for Webdevelopment (Quanta outdated, KDevelop on the way, bluefish lacking good projectmanagement including comfortable ftp, kompozer crappy. geany too complex ...), Accounting (gnucash too geeky, Kmymoney getting there, all others no hbci...), simple ERP not existent and so forth. I'd be willing to pay for stuff ... cya, p.